# On Android 11, Notification.DeleteIntent received callback when Notification been cancelled or clicked. It should not be called when clicked

Tags: android, android-notifications, cancellation

Recently we found an extra callback from our `Notification.DeleteIntent` when clicking on the Notification. Then we found out that it only happened on Android 11, not Android 9 or before (not sure about Android 10, do not have devices of it).

I.e.,

- For Android 9 and before, `Notification.ContentIntent` been called when clicking on the Notification, and `Notification.DeleteIntent` been called when swiping out the Notification.
- For Android 11, `Notification.ContentIntent` been called when clicking on the Notification, and `Notification.DeleteIntent` been called when **clicking on** or swiping out the Notification.

Is it intended behavior of Android 11 platform? Or something is not correct in our codes? Thanks!

```
    public class NotificationClickedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Note: Received callback when Notification been clicked.
        }
    }

    public class NotificationCancelledReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Note: On Android 9 and before, received callback only when Notification been cancelled (swipe out).
            // Note: On Android 11, received callback when Notification been cancelled or clicked.
        }
    }

    {
    ...
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationClickedReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        intent = new Intent(context, NotificationCancelledReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent deletedIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(context);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("title")
                .setContentText("text")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setDeleteIntent(deletedIntent)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
    ...
    }
```